# SCSS mixin dynamic class name evaluates without quotation mark

Tags: sass, styling, mixins, scss-mixins

I'm using the following SCSS mixin

```
@mixin QuintIcon($path, $name, $color) {
  ion-icon {
    &[class*=#{quote($name)}] {
      mask-image: url($path);
      color: #{$color};
    }
  }
}

@include QuintIcon("../../assets/img/tabs/rings.svg", "quint-ring", "#FFF");
```

I expect the following result

```
ion-icon[class*="quint-ring"] {
  mask-image: url("../../assets/img/tabs/rings.svg");
  color: #FFF;
}
```

However i get this

```
ion-icon[class*=quint-ring] {
  mask-image: url("../../assets/img/tabs/rings.svg");
  color: #FFF;
}
```

#### Explanation

The difference between those two code blocks is on the first line right after the '=' symbol. I expect the value to evaluate into a quoted string, but it doesn't, even if I use the [Quote SCSS Function](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html#quote-instance_method). I'm plugging this into Ionic but this has nothing to do with styling, it works only with quotation marks.

#### Experimenting

You can test the following code at [SassMeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
@mixin QuintIcon($path, $name, $color) {
  ion-icon {
    &[class*="#{$name}"] {
      mask-image: url($path);
      color: #{$color};
    }
  }
}

@include QuintIcon("../../assets/img/tabs/rings.svg", "quint-ring", "#FFF");
```

on Sassmeister using LibSass or Sass compiler I get

```
ion-icon[class*="quint-ring"] {
  mask-image: url("../../assets/img/tabs/rings.svg");
  color: #FFF;
}
```

Looks like what you expected.

Also, why does

```
ion-icon[class*=quint-ring] {
  mask-image: url("../../assets/img/tabs/rings.svg");
  color: #FFF;
}
```

not work for you? I can not find a scenario where the resulting selector would be problematic:

```css
div[class*=quint-ring] {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="quint-ring">quint-ring</div>
<div class="squint-ring">squint-ring</div>
<div class="quint-rings">quint-rings</div>
<div class="aaa sfdfsdfsquint-ring">aaa sfdfsdfsquint-ring</div>
<div class="quint-ringsssss bdfdb">quint-ringsssss bdfdb</div>
```

https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/BvLMBW

Comment: Weird, cause I don't get this result, we probably have a different configuration on SassMeister. On my end, I'm using DartSass v1.6.2 which I have no idea what it is. Obviously, it's a compiler but I don't think this works on Ionic

Comment: I confirm that on LibSass compiler works as expected, but doesn't work on Ionic v3 framework

Comment: The only compiler on Sassmeister that removes the quotation marks seems to be DartSass. Is that what Ionic v3 uses?

Comment: Your solution is right, I just messed up an ionic specific thing. Thanks!